# Error when migrating from the NuGet repo *sc-packages-9-1* to *sc-packages*

Tags: nuget

We have the following reference to a Sitecore 9.1 DLL in one of our Visual Studio project:

```
<package id="Sitecore.Abstractions" version="12.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

And everything used to work fine.

Since Sitecore has finished the migration from those Sitecore 9.1 DLLs to the standard NuGet repository *https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/*, we decided to delete the reference to *https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-platform-9-1* from our `NuGet.config`.

However, after doing that, my solution is not able to find the above-mentioned package.

```
Errors in packages.config projects
    Unable to find version '12.0.0' of package 'Sitecore.Abstractions'.          
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Sitecore.Abstractions.12.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Sitecore.Abstractions.12.0.0' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.         
      https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/: Package 'Sitecore.Abstractions.12.0.0' is not found on source 'https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/'.
```